# sidebar menu similar to accordion

Tags: vaadin7

Does anyone know a way to do a sort of accordion menu similar to the vaadin documation [here](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/introduction/intro-overview.html).  Of special importance is to expand and collapse a sub-menu, as per these images:
[image: expanded "Introduction" menu]
Figure 1: expanded "Introduction" menu

[image: collapsed "Introduction" menu]
Figure 2: collapsed "Introduction" menu

To be honest, I don't care so much for the up or down arrow.  I mostly care about being able to click on the caption to expand, then click on it to collapse, independent of other sub-menus.  Any ideas how to do with in Vaadin?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something simple like this. You'll need to create a resource for the up and down arrows, then simply put your content you want to hide into the content VerticalLayout.

```
        Button button = new Button();
        final VerticalLayout content = new VerticalLayout();
        content.setVisible(false);
        button.setIcon(UP_ARROW);
        button.addClickListener(new ClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {


                content.setVisible(!content.isVisible());
                if (content.isVisible())
                {
                    button.setIcon(UP_ARROW);
                }
                else
                {
                    button.setIcon(DOWN_ARROW);
                }


            }
        });


        HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout(button, content);
        addComponent(hl);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the [StackPanel add-on](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/stackpanel-extension-for-vaadin), with quite a few CSS adjustments to my theme common.scss file.  Works rather well for a valo-menu that started as the same sidebar menu they have in the dashboard demo.

See [here](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/14353904) for a fuller discussion, if you are curious.  One of the posters there also suggested using [Tree](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/tree) or [TreeTable](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/tree-table), which also would work in this type of situation, just did not look as nice in my case.